# How to remove/disable pages in viewpager adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I have struggled a lot with my ViewPagerAdapter for remove/disable pages. But nothing happens. Is there any ways to remove pages from a ViewPagerAdapter? Here is my code-
As you can see, I have three positions there. I just want to remove/disable position 1(paragraph 1).

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter2 extends PagerAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    
    String strings[] = {
        
        "paragraph 0",
        "paragraph 1",
        "paragraph 2"
        
    };


    public ViewPagerAdapter2 (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return strings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_lyrics,null);
        final TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_lyricsTextView);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div style='text-align: center'><p>"+strings[position]+"</p></div></body></html>"));
        

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
        
    }

}
```